# Interface for Direct3D class

Tags: c++, directx

**EDIT**:

I've looked through a few tutorials but I'm having a hard time understanding the proper usage of interfaces in C++.

System::Initialize is responsible for initializing the graphics.
iGraphics is the interface where we are either initializing DX9 or DX11 (based off of end-user specs)
D3D contains the functionality for working with DX.

I am trying to call D3D through pure virtual functions so it can be decided at runtime whether we're using DX9, DX11 or - potentially - OpenGL.

**Interfaces.h:**

```
#ifndef _INTERFACES_H_
#define _INTERFACES_H_

#pragma once
class iGraphics
{
public:
    virtual ~iGraphics() {};

    virtual bool vGetGraphics(HWND) = 0;

    virtual void vShutdown() = 0;
    virtual void vRender(float, float, float, float) = 0;
};


#endif
```

**(Partial)D3D.h**

```
class D3D : public iGraphics
{
virtual void vShutdown() override;
virtual void vRender(float, float, float, float) override;
};

class D3D11 : Public D3D

{
public:
    virtual bool vGetGraphics(HWND) override;

private:
    bool CreatePipeline();
    bool InitGraphics();
    bool PrepareD3D(HWND);
};
```

***Problem:***
I've corrected most of the other items and now I'm receiving the error:

```
error C2011: 'D3D11' : 'class' type redefinition
```

All of my headers begin with an ifndef, what else could be causing this?

Comment: The error says __non__-static. It means it __isn't__ static.

Comment: @PawełStawarz Apologies for the oversight, I guess my question is the other way around then. A Pure Virtual function cannot be static so how are the objects dissimilar?

Comment: What are you trying? `vGetD3D11()` returns a `bool`. How do you expect this to cast to `iGraphics**`? You probably won't need a double-pointer. You try to call the method like a static method (with the `class::method()` syntax). You need an object to call the method on: `auto dx11 = new D3D11(); dx11->vGetD3D11();`. Note that this will probably fail, because you didn't inherit `D3D` publicly in `D3D11`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks, made some changes to original post but I'm still having trouble.

Comment: Now it returns `void` which isn't a pointer to an `iGraphics` object either. What's the purpose of this function? `dx11` is already an `iGraphics` object and could be converted to a `shared_ptr<iGraphics>`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler the purpose of the vGetGraphics override is to initialize the DX11, DX9 or OpenGL graphics. From the tutorial I'm working on it looks like I need to grab the iGraphics interface through this shared_ptr before I can call vGetGraphics, is this not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @NicoSchertler as he pointed out most of the errors that needed to be corrected.

I had a lot of problems with this code so it's difficult to summarize all that I had to fix but here's the final code:

**Interfaces.h**

```
#ifndef _INTERFACES_H_
#define _INTERFACES_H_

#pragma once
class iGraphics
{
public:
    virtual ~iGraphics() {};

    virtual bool vGetGraphics(HWND) = 0;

    virtual void vShutdown() = 0;
    virtual void vRender(float, float, float, float) = 0;
};
#endif
```

**D3D.h**

```
class D3D : public iGraphics
{
    virtual void vShutdown();
    virtual void vRender(float, float, float, float);
};

class D3D11 : public D3D
{
public:
    virtual bool vGetGraphics(HWND);

private:
    bool CreatePipeline();
    bool InitGraphics();
    bool PrepareD3D(HWND);
};
```

**D3D.cpp**

```
// Initializes Direct3D
bool D3D11::vGetGraphics(HWND hWnd) 
{

    // Initialize Direct3D
    bool rPrep = PrepareD3D(hWnd);
    if (!rPrep)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Create the pipeline
    bool rPipe = CreatePipeline();
    if (!rPipe)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Initialize graphics
    bool rInitG = InitGraphics();
    if (!rInitG)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

**System.cpp**

```
bool System::Initialize()
{

    // Create Windows interface
    InitializeWindows();

    auto dx11 = new D3D11();
    bool rGetGraphics = dx11->vGetGraphics(hWnd);
    if (!rGetGraphics)
    {
        return false;
    }

return true;
}
```

Would still appreciate any comments/suggestions or a link to a great DirectX tutorial.
Thanks.

Comment: Also a note that System::Initialize is leaking memory. `dx11` is a pointer that is never freed. I recommend you read about `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`. Although I suspect `dx11` is probably handed off or defined elsewhere in your actual code.

Comment: As a side note, you are not using comments right. for example: `/* Create the pipeline */ bool rPipe = CreatePipeline();` The function name already says what it does, so there is no need to repeat that information.